# How to replace a string inside an SQL file with sed

Tags: regex, bash, sed

I have a Multi-site WordPress installation, that contains several sites for the company I work for, and I have produce a bash script, that extracting the database tables for each site separately.

In addition, we title each site based on the location of each copy. In example the local copy of a site it is named like `Site Title - Local`, the staging has a title like `Site Title - Staging` and the production like `Site Title`.

In my script I can use the following `sed` command in order to find and replace the `- Local` to `- Staging`

```
sed -i -e "s/\s\-\sLocal/\ \-\ Staging/g" ${staging_sql_file};
```

But the following doesn't work for removing the string `- Local`:

```
sed -i -e "s/ - Local//g" ${staging_sql_file};
```

I also have try patterns like the following ones:

```
"s/\s\-\sLocal//g"
"s/ \- Local//g"
"s/\s\-\sLocal/\s/g"
"s/ \- Local/ /g"
```

but none of these works.

Can somebody help me with that problem ?

**UPDATE #1**

When I try the regex's I display above, I get an error from `sed`.

**UPDATE #2**

My SQL files are like the following one:

```
LOCK TABLES `wp_16_options` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `wp_16_options` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `wp_16_options` VALUES (1,'siteurl','https://www.site-url.com','yes'),(2,'home','https://www.site-url.com','yes'),(3,'blogname','Site Title - Local','yes'),(4,'blogdescription','Just another multi site wp site','yes'),(5,'users_can_register','0','yes'),...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sed:

```
sed -i.bak 's/[[:blank:]]*-[[:blank:]]*Local//g' "${staging_sql_file}"
```

i.e. use of POSIX class `[[:blank:]]` in place of a horizontal white-space.

Comment: Ok can you show me output of `grep Local "${staging_sql_file}" | cat -vte` command

Comment: Unfortunately not, because the result it's huge.

Comment: Oh that is to save original file with `.bak` extension in case something goes wrong in editing.

Comment: Oh ok ! But I don't mind to backup the original file, as the original files is always a fresh copy of my local database.

Comment: ok but that is unimportant here. Main thing is replacement should work for you and only reason it doesn't work if `sql` file has some invalid characters

Comment: My bash script, it has a standard way that works. The procedure that follows is the following : Extracting a single SQL containing the tables for each of my blogs. Then creates a copy for each of my stages (Staging/Production) in different folder, and then performing the replacement of the URLs and other strings. One of the string I like to replace is the ` - Local` with nothing or a space, but this particular one does not work.

Answer (score 1):

```
[SO]$ cat file
Site Title - Local
Site Title - Staging
Site Title

[SO]$ sed 's/ - Local//g' file
Site Title
Site Title - Staging
Site Title
```